# how to setup version controlling system in small team

Tags: eclipse, version-control

I'm a web developer and would like to setup one system as server which can have all the source code which my team will develop.

My worries here is we all use different different OS (windows, Ubuntu, CentOS) but we work from the same place. I want to have some version controlling tool which allows us to do development efficiently.

Currently we are spending more time to integrate each other code in your code and fixing code according to new/old code.

We all use eclipse Juno. I really appreciate if someone can send me step by step guide to setup the version control system on Ubuntu or CentOS system.

I want this version controlling system should work in local only. I don't want to host my code on some 3rd party server. I want them in my local server only.

Thank you,

Comment: What's wrong with just using good old svn?  This isn't platform dependent and you can host it on your own server...

Comment: You tagged this question `eclipse`. Is Eclipse integration a necessity?

Comment: @Jace Browning: i tag eclipse because i'm working on broadleaf e-commerce which is java based code and using eclips for development. Now i want something with eclipse so i can directly get files under my repository when i say check-in or checkout.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Git with [Gitlab](https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq#installation). Just follow the setup instructions on your Linux based local server.

Git works also with Windows. Check http://git-scm.com/ or http://uncod.in/blog/installing-tortoisegit-on-windows7/

You can use [Egit](http://www.eclipse.org/egit/) to integrate with Eclipse.

Good Luck!

Comment: I suggest you to adopt GitFlow - scalable Git branching model: https://vimeo.com/16018419 or http://www.slideshare.net/davidpaluy/git-flow-introduction

Comment: @david99world: I'm fine with SVN also but i want something in local server only which can be access by my team member. I'm not very expert to setup servers and all... I wan step by step guide to setup this environment for my team.

Comment: Do you have a server? Is it Linux/ Ubuntu? There is a very good step-by-step guide to setup GitFlow https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/blob/master/doc/install/installation.md

Comment: If you don't want to setup your own server, you always can use https://bitbucket.org . It has private repository for up to five members for free.

Comment: Hi Dpaluy, thanks for quick response and provide lots of information. I try Egit and unfortunately its not working in local. I don't want to host my source code online on any other server :(. Is that possible to have something in local only??? 

Like i want to use my server as i.e. (172.xx.xx.xx.:8080/repoName) is that possible to use something like this???

I'm using centOS 6.4 machine as and server and want Ubuntu and windows user to connect this server and work on code with checkin and checkout to maintain the source code.

Comment: Egit is a plugin for eclipse. It's not a server. The server is Gitlab. Just follow the installation instructions: https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/blob/master/doc/install/installation.md  Check this Demo: http://demo.gitlabhq.com/users/sign_in You can setup such web service on your local network.

Answer (score 0):

I really enjoy [Veracity](http://veracity-scm.com/). It's cross-platform and you can run it as a sever that only exists on your local network. The interface is fairly similar to Subversion, but is distributed version control. Here's a quick introduction:

http://veracity-scm.com/qa/questions/53/ive-installed-veracity-how-do-i-get-started-using-it